# Is it possible to compile the linux kernel (for BeagleBone) in OS X?

Tags: linux, macos, linux-kernel

I want to get started with compiling the linux kernel to run on a Beaglebone. Is it possible to do this from the OS X environment? I am running Mavericks and have updated my macports repository. Are there any other specific tools i will need?

I am following a document on how to do this, but it is specifically targeted for a machine thats runs a distro of Linux.

Is it possible to do the entire process from the OS X environment ? Is there something specific that i should watch out for or something that i should do beforehand? I am prepared to do additional work if necessary - if at all it can be done.

It would be really helpful if someone can help with some information regarding this or point me to some available documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to get this to work, but you're setting yourself up for a miserable experience.

Just install a virtual machine an build from a Linux system.